# Translate object by swiping in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to translate my sphere while swiping my finger on the screen.
With the code below I need to swipe again and again to move it forward.
How can I translate an object forward by swiping only once?

```
public float speed;

void FixedUpdate ()
{  
    if (Input.touchCount > 0 && 
        Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Ended || (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)))
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime*speed);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code makes the object move for the exact moment when the TouchPhase has Ended. In order to push the object, try applying a force.

Modified C# example from [Unity Tutorials](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/topics/physics/adding-physics-forces):

```
public float speed;
public Rigidbody rb;

void Start() 
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

void FixedUpdate() 
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0 &&
        Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Ended || (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)))
    {
        rb.AddForce(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * speed);
    }
}
```

You need to add a `Rigidbody3D` Component to the object, if you use this technique.